# javascript parameters reference errors

Tags: javascript, parameters

i was trying to make a photo gallery where user can click the link and show different photo but itry to put the parameters as a name but it keeps getting error says that said reference error but when i try to use number like 0,1,2,3,4,5 everything goes normal exactly like i want.My question is how to make the parameters to be a name instead of a number ?

```
  <body>
<img src="../bab2/images/Gusion.png" width="400px" alt="" id="gambar">
<a href="#" onclick="ganti(gusion)">1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="ganti(selena)">2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="ganti(2)">3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="ganti(3)">4</a>
<a href="#" onclick="ganti(4)">5</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ganti(nama){
    var lokasi = '../bab2/images/' + nama + '.png';
    document.getElementById('gambar').src =lokasi;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass names as parameters you need to pass them as Strings, i.e., enter the name within quotes. Here is the modified code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ganti('gusion')">1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="ganti('selena')">2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`gusion` and `selena` are names… specifically, they are **variable names**.

If you want a *string* then you need to [surround it with quotes](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals).